# wordpress plugin do not show up in localhost dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wamp

i have wordpress 4.1.1. i built my theme and now working on my personal site.

I am not working on the live website, i have my localhost created via WAMP.

In WWW i have wpcontent folder and in plugins I copied and paste my own site-specific plugin folder with the .php file to add all my snippets

Actually even if the folder is present under plugin directory, it does not show up in localhost dashboard---> plugins in my local Wordpress admin panel
is it a common issue? any tips?

Thanks in advance.
Paolo

Comment: Tell us which plugin you're trying to install on your localhost instance?

Comment: Can you past your folder structure (so we can check you've put the right things in the right places)?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin i am installing a site specific plugin. It is only a blak php file to add snippets and using custom type fields. not a common known plugin

Comment: @Hobo C:\wamp\www\phobs\wp-content\plugins where "phobs" is the name of my theme . thanks both

Comment: of course in plugin folder i have this \phobs-plugin\phobs-plugin.php

Comment: Now it appears. I changed the code in the .php file. using Sublime, i noticed that there were c omments and the content text inside was color violet. so i thought was that a possible issue. I modify until the comments in /* and */ was grey and save it. then i went in dashobard plugin in my local host and it appeared.

Comment: Solved, (see above my comment) thanks anyway ;)